# react-intl - FormattedDate - DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY (for en-us!)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-intl

I have an application with react-intl injected. Its bilingual - in English and in Polish so i represent dates with . When I represent let's say 12 April 2005 its:

- > 12.04.2005 in Polish
- > 04/12/2005 in English

It confuses everyone as people think about the second date as 4th December. Can i somehow format dates so in English it would be DD/MM/YYYY ?

Comment: Please note that the format MM/DD/YYYY is used by a minority of English speakers and is peculiar to the USA, not English speakers in general. Far better to use an unambiguos format that uses the month name like DD-MMM-YYYY (e.g. 12-Jul-2018) or MMMM D, YYYY (e.g. July 12, 2018).

Answer (score 3):

So, if the locale of your application is working fine, you can just use the FormattedDate component from `react-intl`and it will display the date in the current format.

Assuming that the locale is in place, you'd only have to use it like this:

```
<FormattedDate
    value="12.04.2005"
    day="2-digit"
    month="2-digit"
    year="numeric"
/>
```

The FormattedDate component will use the locale of the application to format it to english or polish (or any other locale you set).
Here is the [reference in the doc](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formatteddate)

Comment: i think he's asking how to overwrite en-US. not the default.... and seems FormattedDate is pretty bad with overwrite? not seeing example.

Comment: I went on a magical journey to find the new location of this react-intl doc, 5 years later. Here it is: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components

Answer (score -1):

There is not much to work with, but see if this helps:

```
let PolishDate = '12.04.2005';
let arr = PolishDate.split('.');
let EnglishDate = arr[1] + '/' + arr[0] + '/' + arr[2];
console.log(EnglishDate);
```

Comment: I could do this but with this library the date changes then the language changes, I cannot format it in such a way. I am looking for sth maybe included in this library... idk

Comment: what 'library' are you referring to?

Comment: he is using react-intl, so react-intl already handle this by displaying the date format according to the current locale.

Comment: @Periback—but where is the current locale sourced from?

Comment: you have to provide it to the intlProvider.. (through a switch button or through some environment settings that you get and define it...) but eventhough, react-intl has the addLocaleData that you need to call for each locale your app supports

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/internationalizing-react-apps/ is a good tutorial to start with react-intl :)

Comment: @Periback—thanks, I think an important part is “*…implement a widget with which the user can change the language intuitively and that they can easily locate within a few seconds.*”

Comment: yes.. in my case, for example, it's a public website with different domains, so I don't need to have a switch button.. I just load the correct locale and json file with the labels based on an environment variable that tells me which environment I am.. Based on it, I set the locale to the intlProvider and load the correct json file with the labels for that specific locale